# Google Maps API v3 does not find it's own suggested location (with autocompletion)

Tags: google-maps-api-3

(It was suggested by Google Maps Developer Direction to post it here)

I am using Google Maps API v3 for my website, this is the address: http://goo.gl/YuyPo Sorry for Romanian language, but it is easy to see the search field and the map, that is universal :)
(or, you can use the official Google Maps API v3 autocompletion example from here: https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete, it reacts the same)

It works quite well, but I if I search for

```
Câmpulung Moldovenesc, Suceava, Romania
```

(exactly like this) the autocompetion works, but if I click the autocompleted value (the one above), it does nothing. It should go to the searched & selected place. The location is valid and you can find it in Google Maps for instance.

It is the same with

```
Cîmpulung Moldovenesc, Suceava, Romania
```

(in Romanian language Câmpulung is the correct one, but till aprox 15 years ago it was Cîmpulung, and î became â in the middle of words)

That search gets me to that town only if I spell it with i (`Cimpulung Moldovenesc`).

Originally, the code was the one from that example I provided the link (in my example the code is modified for other needs I have beside just searching and autocompletion):

> Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Places Autocomplete
>
> ```
> <style type="text/css">
>   body {
>     font-family: sans-serif;
>     font-size: 14px;
>   }
>   #map_canvas {
>     height: 400px;
>     width: 600px;
>     margin-top: 0.6em;
>   }
> </style>
>
> <script type="text/javascript">
>   function initialize() {
>     var mapOptions = {
>       center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8688, 151.2195),
>       zoom: 13,
>       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
>     };
>     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
>       mapOptions);
>
>     var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
>     var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
>
>     autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
>
>     var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
>     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
>       map: map
>     });
>
>     google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
>       infowindow.close();
>       var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
>       if (place.geometry.viewport) {
>         map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
>       } else {
>         map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
>         map.setZoom(17);  // Why 17? Because it looks good.
>       }
>
>       var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
>           place.icon,
>           new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
>           new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
>           new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
>           new google.maps.Size(35, 35));
>       marker.setIcon(image);
>       marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
>
>       var address = '';
>       if (place.address_components) {
>         address = [(place.address_components[0] &&
>                     place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
>                    (place.address_components[1] &&
>                     place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
>                    (place.address_components[2] &&
>                     place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
>                   ].join(' ');
>       }
>
>       infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address);
>       infowindow.open(map, marker);
>     });
>
>     // Sets a listener on a radio button to change the filter type on Places
>     // Autocomplete.
>     function setupClickListener(id, types) {
>       var radioButton = document.getElementById(id);
>       google.maps.event.addDomListener(radioButton, 'click', function() {
>         autocomplete.setTypes(types);
>       });
>     }
>
>     setupClickListener('changetype-all', []);
>     setupClickListener('changetype-establishment', ['establishment']);
>     setupClickListener('changetype-geocode', ['geocode']);
>   }
>   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
> </script>   </head>   <body>
> <div>
>   <input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50">
>   <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-all" checked="checked">
>   <label for="changetype-all">All</label>
>
>   <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-establishment">
>   <label for="changetype-establishment">Establishments</label>
>
>   <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-geocode">
>   <label for="changetype-geocode">Geocodes</lable>
> </div>
> <div id="map_canvas"></div>   </body> </html>
> ```

Is there a solution for this or should I somehow file a bug report? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
    var input = document.getElementById('searchTextFieldWhereMe');
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input,options);
    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', this.map);

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
           infowindow.close();
           var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
           if (place.geometry.viewport) {
              alfamap.map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
           } else {
             alfamap.map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
             alfamap.map.setZoom(16);
           }

           alfamap.marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);

           var address = '';
           if (place.address_components) {
             address = [(place.address_components[0] &&
                         place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
                        (place.address_components[1] &&
                         place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
                        (place.address_components[2] &&
                         place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
                       ].join(', ');
           }

           infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address);
           infowindow.open(alfamap.map, marker);
         });
```

Works for me