# Google Maps autocomplete prompt does not match returned location

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Google Maps autocomplete is working in almost all cases, but behaves strangely on one address.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/yr8z1zdr/), thanks to @geocodezip, showing the issue.

This is similar to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050532/google-maps-api-v3-does-not-find-its-own-suggested-location-with-autocompletio), except in that issue no place was returned. This returns a similarly named place, but in a different location.

The correct address appears in the suggestions box, but is different on the `place_changed` event. The two addresses are located a large distance from one another.

[image: Differing results for autocomplete]

As can be seen, this is reproducible on the autocomplete demo, so I don't think it's an implementation issue. Has anyone seen this kind of behaviour and managed to fix it?

In addition, requesting query predictions via the `AutocompleteService` for the address that is returned by the original autocomplete suggestion returns `ZERO_RESULTS`.

```
new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
    service.getQueryPredictions({ input: '77 Main Road, Crowthorne AH, Sandton, South Africa' }, function(predictions, status) {
      if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        alert(status);
        return;
      }

      predictions.forEach(function(prediction) {
        console.log(prediction);

      });
    });
```

Comment: RE: why isn't this code working flag, the code I'm using is identical to Google's own example, which is not working, for this specific set of addresses.

Comment: [Fiddle that exhibits the issue (with the part of the address required to get the result)](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/yr8z1zdr/) (and a details request for the resulting place_id).  Looks like a definite issue with the Places API.

Comment: Any idea of a workaround? When the `place_changed` event fires, I can get the correct address as per the autocomplete from the input box before it gets updated to the wrong one, but obviously it's a formatted String, not broken down into the places components.

Comment: Seems to be a data problem in the places data.  Perhaps use the Google Maps tools to report it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue that you are experiencing was reported in Google issue tracker. You can have a look and add your comment here:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35830687

Let me explain what is the problem. If you check the place ID documentation, you will see that there are two options for place IDs.

https://developers.google.com/places/place-id#id-overview

The short place IDs like `ChIJrTLr-GyuEmsRBfy61i59si0` and the long place IDs like `EisxMyBNYXJrZXQgU3RyZWV0LCBXaWxtaW5ndG9uLCBOQyAyODQwMSwgVVNB`. When you see the short place ID that means Google has an exact feature for this address in their database, when you see the long place ID that means Google doesn't have an exact feature and tries to interpolate an address. Sometimes the interpolation works differently in autocomplete and in place details, so in this case you observe the issue described in your question and reported as [bug 35830687](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35830687).

Now let's check what is the place ID in your example. I execute the following place autocomplete request:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=77%20Main%20Road%2C%20Crowthorne%20AH&key=API_KEY`

I can see the following text in the response

```
"predictions":[
  {
    "description":"77 Main Road, Crowthorne AH, Sandton, South Africa",
    "id":"a0ab043870d062bad00d5ce2ed91faaf7250efbe",
    "matched_substrings":[
      {
        "length":12,
        "offset":0
      },
      {
        "length":13,
        "offset":14
      }
    ],"place_id":"EjI3NyBNYWluIFJvYWQsIENyb3d0aG9ybmUgQUgsIFNhbmR0b24sIFNvdXRoIEFmcmljYQ",
....
```

The place ID is the long one `EjI3NyBNYWluIFJvYWQsIENyb3d0aG9ybmUgQUgsIFNhbmR0b24sIFNvdXRoIEFmcmljYQ` and that means the address is interpolated.

The most straight forward fix might be creating an exact address for '77 Main Road, Crowthorne AH, Sandton, South Africa'. There is only one way to report missing data to Google and it's described in the following support help:

https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3094045

You should send feedback and let Google know that address '77 Main Road, Crowthorne AH, Sandton, South Africa' is missing. Otherwise you should wait while bug 35830687 is solved.

I hope this explains your doubt!

Comment: Thanks, that explains it. There are a number of these because of the nature of the addresses we're searching, so if there's a long `place_id` I think I may just use the terms returned by the autocomplete service and have them manually confirm the address.

Comment: Could I detect this by just checking the length of the returned `place_id` in the listener?

Comment: As far as I know the exact features have a short place ID that starts with `Ch...`, the interpolated features have a long place ID that starts with `E...`. You can apply this logic, but be aware that Google can change the format without any previous notification.